# SaveAs issue cannot access file

Tags: save, runtime-error, save-as

I am beside myself!  I have this simple code and it keeps giving me the run time error ....cannot access file "C:(various characters)..... on save as.  This is so simple I SHOULD be able to correct, but GAH!  I have Dimmed S,  and outputPath as String.

This is the code:

```
       outputPath = "C:\LLC"
    
    'Create Email Sheets Loop
       Set PF = Sheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("EmailsTable").PivotFields("Responsible Party")
   
   
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

       For Each Pi In PF.PivotItems
        Pi.DataRange.ShowDetail = True
        ActiveSheet.Name = Pi.Name
    
       ActiveSheet.Copy
       With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
           Set rList = .Range
           .Unlist
       End With
    
       ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Select
    
       S = Range("J2").Value
       
       ChDir outputPath
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
           outputPath & S & ".xlsx" _
           , FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
  
       ActiveSheet.Delete
    
       Next Pi
    
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thank you for your assistance.

I have tried to name the file as the sheet name, I have created all kinds of different name variables, I'm just frustrated.